# android animation has become choppy/laggy. loosing frames on less powerful devices

Tags: android, animation, frames

I have the following activity layout with many `<framelayout>` layers each containing images at different positions on the screen. some of the images are animated simaltenously. The animations run smoothly on tablets but are very choppy on mobile phones. Is there a problem with the layout design? Are there any tricks to avoid choppy animations?

following layout xml is simplified to shorten it
`

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <ImageView .../>
            <View/>
            <LinearLayout >
                <View/>
                <FrameLayout >
                    <FrameLayout >
                        <ImageView .../>
                    </FrameLayout>
                    <LinearLayout >
                        <FrameLayout>
                            <TextView/>
                        </FrameLayout>
                        <FrameLayout >
                            <TextView/>
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
                <View/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View/>
            <ImageView .../>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout >
            <FrameLayout >
                <ImageView .../>
                <TextView/>
            </FrameLayout>
            <View />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout >
    <LinearLayout >
        <View/>
        <FrameLayout >
            <ImageView.../>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <View/>
        <LinearLayout >
            <View/>
            <ImageView .../>
            <FrameLayout >
                <ImageView .../>
                <ImageView .../>
            </FrameLayout>
            <View/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout >
    <View/>
    <FrameLayout >
        <LinearLayout >
            <View />
            <ImageView .../>
            <View/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout >
            <TextView/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <View/>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <View/>
        <FrameLayout >
            <ImageView ... />
            <ImageView .../>
            <ImageView .../>
            <LinearLayout >
                <View/>
                <LinearLayout >
                    <View />
                    <LinearLayout >
                        <LinearLayout >
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout >
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout>
    <View >
    </View>
    <LinearLayout >
        <View>
        </View>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <View >
        </View>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <View>
        </View>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
    <View/>
    <LinearLayout >
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
        <ImageView .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: First thing you should try is to simplify the layout. It's too deep and that will be expensive to handle. See http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#layoutopt  Also as you noted, if you have a less powerful device, then the things it'll be able to do will be less complex than what a more capable device can handle.

Comment: I have tried to make the layout more flat than deep(multiple layers using framelayout) with many layers getting visible only momentarily. Should this affect animation? I guessed an invisible layer will be ignored by the renderer hence not affecting performance.

Comment: @user3193606 have u got the solution? I m also having same kind of heavy layout. full of views and layout